# what's wrong with these code? why it not sort preview image upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Here is the full code for html5 multiple upload file with removeable and preview image

but I don't know in `function handleFileSelect(e)`  why it show the preview images with wrong sorting when choose more than 2 files?  (Although, it upload to my folder correctly sort  but I still want it to show preview with correct sorting)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Proper Title</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #selectedFiles img {
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .delete_img{
        cursor:pointer;
        color:red;
        font-size:14px;
        margin-left:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="myForm" method="post">

        Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
        Multiple Files: <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple><br/>

        <div id="selectedFiles"></div>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>



    <script>
    var selDiv = "";
    var storedFiles = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

        selDiv = $("#selectedFiles"); 
        $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

        $("body").on("click", ".delete_img", removeFile);
    });

    function handleFileSelect(e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
        filesArr.forEach(function(f) {          

            if(!f.type.match("image.*")) {
                return;
            }
            storedFiles.push(f);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'> <span class='delete_img'> DEL </span><br>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
                selDiv.append(html);

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
        });

    }

    function handleForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value; //get value จาก form input
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;


        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('username', username); //มาใส่ในajax object formdata เพื่อเตรียมส่งเข้าฝั่งserver
        data.append('email', email);

        for(var i=0, len=storedFiles.length; i<len; i++) {
            data.append('files[]', storedFiles[i]);  //อย่าลืม []
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);  
                //alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
                window.location = "http://www.google.com";
            }
        }

        xhr.send(data);
    }

    function removeFile(e) {
        var img = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("img")
        var file = img.getAttribute('data-file');
        for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
            if(storedFiles[i].name === file) {
                storedFiles.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the total upload size of your files overcomes the max_upload_limit.Usually is 2 MB.As i tested your code in liveweave i don't have problem (5 images).Check the total size of your files. How much is it?

Comment: but this is not about upload size because it's just preview image  (before upload)

Comment: Try to check it in liveweave.